# making a separate table, based off a previous table, omitting non value numbers

Tags: excel, cells, worksheet

I am having trouble getting the right formula for what I am trying to do.

basically, I need to enter data into a table to submit to accounting. I take data from one table and put it into another table. The formulas I have been using require me to all ALL data and accounting only want the data with numerical values.

sheet a

red $7.95
blue $0.00
green $2.00
yellow $1.00
orange $0.00

this is a sample sheet

sheet b
red  $7.95
blue  $0.00
green  $2.00
yellow  $1.00
orange  $0.00

tax 1

grand total 11.95

this is the sheet I need it to go to.

As you can see the blue and orange have a 0 total and what I want to do is omit them from the second list if they have the 0 total. Ive tried various codings but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

You could use filtering to remove rows where the value is 0. If you copy a filtered selection, only the visible data will get pasted.

As for doing this with functions, this isn't really something Excel is designed to do - it's designed to calculate rather than present data, so you're probably venturing into VBA, which is probably overkill.